# Text file is read incorrectly (partly)

Tags: ruby

I have `myscr` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

while $stdin.getc
  puts "char \n"
  puts $stdin.getc
end

puts $stdin.read.inspect
```

When I execute command:

```
cat foo.txt | ruby mysrc
```

I have following output:

```
char 
o
char 

char 
a
char 

char 
a
char 

""
```

So as you can see, it doesn't start with first character, also, for some reason the whole string of `.read` turns to be empty, as well as some characters from `.getc`, and some are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `getc` twice attempts to fetch two characters. Maybe what you mean is:

```
while (char = $stdin.getc)
  puts "Char: %s" % char
end
```

Now any characters you've read are consumed, so you'll need to save them if you want to use those for later input.

Comment: thanks, I basically wanted to read file by character, no to load it in memory at whole, it is tricky result